# Counting values in foreach loop returns only 1 result

Tags: php

I have this code to select some values from database, values are example (-10, 1.4, 5.23, 0.20, -1.45 ..... ), so i need to split them by positive, negative and neutral.

So i do that and display results fine, but i can't count how many of them there are, for example i have over 50 positive values, but it display me only 1, but if i use var_dump($a); i get all of them.

How can i count how many values there are in each if statement ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT numbers FROM mytable WHERE uid = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$cnt = $stmt->rowCount();

echo "Total entries " . $cnt . "<br>"; // returns total count of results

// var_dump($result);

foreach ($result as $rez) {
    $a = $rez['orderprofit']; // all values : positive, negative and neutral (zero)

    //var_dump($a);

    if ($a > 0) {
        var_dump($a);
        $positive_values = count($a); //(count($a) / $cnt)*100 . '%';
    } elseif ($a < 0) {
        $negative_values = $a;
    } elseif ($a == 0) {
        $neutral_values = $a;
    }
}
```

Var_dump returns me a results like this, so anything with array don't works, if i try it say's array to string conversion :

```
string(3) "0.9" string(3) "4.7" string(3) "6.9" string(3) "5.4" string(3) "5.4" 
string(3) "7.9" string(3) "5.9" string(5) "17.21" string(1) "5" string(3) "4.5" 
string(3) "4.7" string(1) "5" string(3) "5.4" string(3) "5.8" string(3) "5.9" 
string(3) "4.7" string(3) "5.4" string(3) "6.9" string(3) "4.5" string(1) "5" 
string(3) "4.7" string(3) "5.4"
```

Ok, here is and image, maybe will help more than this data
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always reset your counting. The following may be a good approach, if `$row['orderprofit']` really contains a numeric value:

```
<?php

$positive_values = 0;
$negative_values = 0;
$neutral_values = 0;

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $a = $row['orderprofit'];


    if ($a > 0) {
        $positive_values++;
    } elseif ($a < 0) {
        $negative_values++;
    } elseif ($a == 0) {
        $neutral_values++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could push values into an array then [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) how many elements are in that array.

For example :

```
$positive_values = array();
$negative_values = array();
$neutral_values = array();

foreach ($result as $rez) {
    $a = $rez['orderprofit']; // all values : positive, negative and neutral (zero)

    if ($a > 0) {
        $positive_values[] = $a;
    } elseif ($a < 0) {
        $negative_values[] = $a;
    } elseif ($a == 0) {
        $neutral_values[] = $a;
    }
}

echo "count positive values : " . count($positive_values) . "<br />";
echo "count negative values : " . count($negative_values) . "<br />";
echo "count neutral values : " . count($neutral_values) . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

> declare  $positive_values , $negative_values ,$neutral_values and instead of count use $positive_values++

**count** *Count all elements in an array, or something in an object*

Comment: I see you have a bad habit using blockquotes for something other than what they were intended for. This is discussed in meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355183/1415724 - would you mind formatting it properly and doing the same for all of your other answers?

Comment: Ohk bro...i am new so..but next time ..i try something new

Comment: what do you mean "next time"? just edit them, you do know how to edit, right?

Comment: I take it that you're not going to answer me nor edit.

Answer (score 0):

Declare three distinct variables, one that stores the count of positive values (`$posi`), one that stores the count of null values (`$zero`) and one that stores the count of negative values (`$nega`). Inside your `foreach` loop, check the current value `$a` and increment the proper variable. Example:

```
<?php

$posi = 0;
$zero = 0;
$nega = 0;

foreach ($result as $rez)
{
    $a = $rez['orderprofit'];

    if ($a == 0) {
        ++$zero;
    } elseif ($a > 0) {
        ++$posi;
    } else {
        ++$nega;
    }
}

echo 'Positive Values: '.$posi;
echo 'Zero Values: '.$zero;
echo 'Negative Values: '.$nega;

?>
```